# Update axis on zoom with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart with a zoom\pan functionality as per [Mark Bostock's example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) however, whilst the chart itself is rescaling, the X Axis is not.

I'm trying to trigger the redraw as so:

```
var viewPort = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(xScale)
    .on('brush', function () {
        var newDomain = viewPort.empty() ? xScale.domain() : viewPort.extent();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(newDomain, null, 2));

        detailsChart.setXDomain(newDomain);
        detailsChart.renderAxis();
        detailsChart.renderSeries();
    });
```

The `renderAxis` looks like this:

```
function () {
            xAxis.scale(xScale);
            all.select('x.axis')
                .call(xAxis);
        }
```

I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vxfhy973/) showing it.

Comment: Is that a typo?  Should be `all.select('.x.axis')`, you are missing the `.` in front of the `x`.

Comment: YES!  That is it.  Thank you so much.  I'd assumed it was an error in my understanding.